# Notifications barely appearing (Nexus 6P)

Tags: notifications, notification-bar, push-notifications

I have been having this problem in which some apps (examples would be Business Calendar 2 and Telegram) don't show notification properly. The do appear, but only for a split second and then immidiately disappear, without even making a sound. It's a problem with these apps because the way I use them notifications are pretty important to me.

I've been reading a bit and managed to figure out that it might be either an issue with the android version (which I don't believe it is, since it's the latest version and I haven't heard the same problem from any of my friends), or a specific app that prevents other apps from showing notifications. Is there any known app that does that? Or is there another possible cause for the symptoms?

Any ideas for a fix would be great, thanks

Comment: @beeshyams 1. It isn't rooted 2. I'm pretty much looking for a fix, but it would be interesting to know the reason for this issue

Comment: Lol, sorry - I meant the post ^-^'

Comment: If I do fix it, I will self answer, of course

Comment: Ok here's my approach. Using automation app [Macrodroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid). Download and give it all permissions it asks for . Set up Trigger: Notification Received > select app ; Action: display Notification select from the **`...`** button (s) what you want displayed along with a different notification sound. You will now get a message on your notification bar that you have a notification from that app. Go to app and check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured up the "problem" - Clean Master had the notification cleaner turned on. I just had to turn it off, and everything is back to normal now.

Comment: It might be useful to read this latest (2018/11/26) [Android Central](https://www.androidcentral.com/eight-android-apps-2-billion-downloads-are-committing-ad-click-fraud) blog report about "Clean Master" and its ad-click actions.